# want to show / hide only the specified elements in jQuery iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code where I want to show / hide different text based upon a mouseover. I am using a data-global-id value and want to iterate through the children of the item-list and hide all but specified value (item-1 for data-global-id=1 for example):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item-list').hide();
    $('.h').mouseover(function() {
      // need to hide everything but the 1 or 2
      var id = $(this).data('global-id');
      var chil=$('.item-list').children();
      $.each(chil, function(i,v){
        alert(i);
        console.log(v);
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<style>
.h{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<ul>
    <li><div class='h' data-global-id="1">Client 1</div></li>
    <li><div class='h' data-global-id="2">Client 2</div></li>
</ul>

<ul class="item-list">
    <li class="item-1">
        Lorem ipsum jtjtjt, etc...
    </li>
    <li class="item-2">
        Lorem ipsum, etc...
    </li>                      
</ul>
```

How would I specify in the each loop to hide everything and just show the item+data-global-id value? Is there a better / easier way to do this?

thx

Comment: I think you should be using `each()` instead of `$.each()`, since you're iterating a collection of jQuery objects and not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want, but I'll give it a shot anyway,

Since you're already using jQuery for your project, you can do a direct search based on the `data-global-id` value as below

```
//Provide the same global-id key to each .item-list member
//Then do the following in your mouse over func
 var id = $(this).data('global-id');
 var chil=$('.item-list').children().show().
             not('[data-global-id="'+ id +'"]').hide();
```

### Edit - Fiddle Added

Check out the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zqj7n/1/)

Comment: hmm... that looks like it's hiding both. sorry, my jQuery skills leave a lot to be desired

Comment: really? I just tested it out, did you run the fiddle? Go to the javascript window and press ctrl + enter

Comment: hmm... both elements are hiding for me when I mouse over; not sure if this is how jQuery handles hide / show

Comment: I am so sorry, my mistake, wrong fiddle - check it now. I'd not saved my changes before

Comment: cool. working now. Does the data-global-id limit the browswers it will work on? Or is jQuery able to normalize that?

Comment: well you'll have to try that out. As far as I know, it should.

Comment: also, if you find this answer solves your problem, could you accept it?